# How to add values in a single tuple in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples

I am newbie in python. So, I have a doubt about this code :

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 4,5
d = (a,b,c)
print d
```

When I run this, I got an output as :

```
> (1, 2, (4, 5))
```

But my expected output is :

```
> (1,2,4,5)
```

How can I get my expected output? Can u give me a solution **without importing any packages**?

**It is not duplicate of that question because I need it based on a single variable no need for list.**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Something like `print (1,2,4,5)` ?

Comment: @hlt It is not a duplicate because i am not testing a list .I need work with variables

Comment: please mention that.why all you vote -1 to me

Comment: what u mean by *c ?? is it a pointer concept??

Comment: `*` unpacks the argument out of tuples and list

Comment: Is it valid in the list concept

Comment: @bobmarti It wouldn't work here as it can only be used in  function arguments, calling functions and tuple unpacking and not for creating tuples.

Comment: then why all are vote -1 to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c` is `4,5` i.e. a `tuple`.

You need to do something like this :

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 4,5
d = (a, b) + c # This will add elements of tuple c to tuple (a,b)
print(d)
```

This will result in :

```
(1, 2, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean inserting an element in python tuple, that can be done like this,

```
a = ('howdy', '100.00', '200.00')
a = list(a)
a.insert(3, 'cowboy')
a = tuple(a)
print a
```

**Output:**

```
('howdy', '100.00', '200.00', 'cowboy')
```